# opencv_annotation not recognised by windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, opencv

I am using OpenCV in windows. When I am using this command in windows command prompt then I am getting an error as opencv_annotation is not recognised as the internal or external command.

opencv_annotation --annotations=/C:\Users\harsh\Desktop/annotation.txt --images=C:\Users\harsh\Desktop/pos/

Comment: Before to launch this command, your command prompt needs to be in the same folder than the executable **opencv_annotation.exe**. If you want to launch this command from a different place, you will have to add the path to the executable in your _environment variables_.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build it using CMake.

Comment: It doesn't provide the answer to the question btw!